# How groupby between flag values from different columns with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Supposing I have a dataframe like this:

| Date | is_start | is_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-16 10:40 | False | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:41 | False | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:42 | False | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:43 | **True** | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:44 | False | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:45 | False | **True** |
| 2021-07-16 10:46 | False | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:47 | **True** | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:48 | False | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:49 | False | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:50 | False | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:51 | False | **True** |
| 2021-07-16 10:52 | False | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:53 | False | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:54 | **True** | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:55 | False | False |

I would like to be able to use groupby (or something similar in terms of efficiency) to create groups of rows in between (and including) their respective is_start and is_end flags. E.g.:

### Group 1

| Date | is_start | is_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-16 10:43 | **True** | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:44 | False | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:45 | False | **True** |

### Group 2

| Date | is_start | is_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-16 10:47 | **True** | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:48 | False | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:49 | False | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:50 | False | False |
| 2021-07-16 10:51 | False | **True** |

I am hoping there is a solution to this without going down the route of looping with iterrows, but thus far, it’s eluding me.

### Additionally...

(but not as important)

It would also be useful to have a way of separately identifying the unfinished group that starts at 2021-07-16 10:54

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using some `cumsum` would do the trick. first on is_start that would create a group id

```
df['gr'] = df['is_start'].cumsum()
print(df)
                Date  is_start  is_end  gr
0   2021-07-16 10:40     False   False   0
1   2021-07-16 10:41     False   False   0
2   2021-07-16 10:42     False   False   0
3   2021-07-16 10:43      True   False   1
4   2021-07-16 10:44     False   False   1
5   2021-07-16 10:45     False    True   1
6   2021-07-16 10:46     False   False   1
7   2021-07-16 10:47      True   False   2
8   2021-07-16 10:48     False   False   2
9   2021-07-16 10:49     False   False   2
10  2021-07-16 10:50     False   False   2
11  2021-07-16 10:51     False    True   2
12  2021-07-16 10:52     False   False   2
13  2021-07-16 10:53     False   False   2
14  2021-07-16 10:54      True   False   3
15  2021-07-16 10:55     False   False   3
```

Then use again `cumsum` on is_end, `shift` it to include the ending row. Substract this to the column gr created before to remove rows after the end. Multiply by itself.

```
df['gr'] = (df['gr'] - df['is_end'].cumsum().shift(fill_value=0))*df['gr']
print(df)
                Date  is_start  is_end  gr
0   2021-07-16 10:40     False   False   0
1   2021-07-16 10:41     False   False   0
2   2021-07-16 10:42     False   False   0
3   2021-07-16 10:43      True   False   1
4   2021-07-16 10:44     False   False   1
5   2021-07-16 10:45     False    True   1
6   2021-07-16 10:46     False   False   0
7   2021-07-16 10:47      True   False   2
8   2021-07-16 10:48     False   False   2
9   2021-07-16 10:49     False   False   2
10  2021-07-16 10:50     False   False   2
11  2021-07-16 10:51     False    True   2
12  2021-07-16 10:52     False   False   0
13  2021-07-16 10:53     False   False   0
14  2021-07-16 10:54      True   False   3
15  2021-07-16 10:55     False   False   3
```

now to get the groups and stop the unfinished one, you can do:

```
for gr, dfg in df.loc[df['gr']>0].groupby('gr'):
    if not dfg['is_end'].any(): print(f'unfinished groupe{gr}', dfg)
    print(f'groupe{gr}', dfg)
```

Note: this works only if there is no True in is_end before is_start

Comment: Apologies if this should be a new question, but supposing I only wanted to create groups when a minimum row count is met (e.g. 5 rows of data between, and inclusive of, is_start and is_end), could that logic be incorporated into the original groupby?

Comment: @HapiDaze in the loop for, you could add another condition after the first one `if len(dfg)<5: print(f'group {gr} not enough rows', dfg)`. that say the numbering of valid groups won't be consecutive anymore